# PK as ROWGUIDCOL or use a separate rowguid column?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, merge-replication

There's a long-winded debate going on here so I'd like to hear other opinions.

I have many tables with uniqueidentifier clustered PK. Whether this is a good idea is out of scope here (and it's not going to change anytime soon).

Now, the database has to be merge published and the DEVs are advocating the use of a separate rowguid column instead of marking the existing PK as the ROWGUIDCOL.

Basically, they say that the application should never bring into its domain something that is used by replication only (it's only "DBA stuff" for them).

From a performance standpoint, I see no reason why I should add a new column to do something I could do with an existing one. Moreover, since it's only "DBA stuff", why not let the DBA choose?

I kind of understand the DEVs' point, but I still disagree.

Thoughts?

**EDIT:** I just want to add that I'm in the minority in this debate and the DEVs questioning my position are people I respect and trust. This is the reason why I resorted to  asking for opinions.
I might also be missing something and could have misunderstood their point.

Comment: Is there any chance that a PK value may need to change in the future?

Comment: No, not really. It's a surrogate key, so the app doesn't really do much with that column. It never changes and it's never displayed to the users.

Comment: Why do they want a separate rowguidcol? And what scheme in general would they choose, if they could, for the PK, and why?

Comment: @spaghettidba Speaking of crossing domains, how often do you tell them what design patterns they should or shouldn't be using in their app code? Maybe they should stick to their "domain"? ;-). Besides, adding a 16 byte column to all tables would be horrible for performance and provide no benefit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Basically, they say that the application should never bring into its domain something that is used by replication only (it's only "DBA stuff" for them).

I agree completely. But... the primary key *isn't* only used for replication (presumably the application uses it in *some* way). The argument makes no sense in this context.

In any event, as far as I'm aware, there are only 2 ways for this "DBA stuff" to cross the domain boundary:

1. If the application is using queries that reference the `ROWGUIDCOL` column like this:

   ```
   DECLARE @a table (id uniqueidentifier ROWGUIDCOL);

   SELECT ROWGUIDCOL FROM @a;
   ```

   I'm assuming none of your columns have this property yet, so the application wouldn't be doing this. (By the way, `ROWGUIDCOL` is a completely separate concept from replication. It just so happens that merge replication uses it.)
2. The primary key column would no longer be updatable. If the application is doing this and changes aren't going to be made to use another algorithm, there's *no choice* but to add a new column to the table, and therefore no discussion is necessary.

Other than those behaviours, the `ROWGUIDCOL` property is completely transparent. You can add it, and the application would never know. *Any* type of *data replication* scenario should be as transparent as possible to applications.

Comment: Thanks for answering. No, the application isn't doing 1. nor 2. For sake of completeness, some tables are already decorated with the ROWGUIDCOL property in the PK.

Comment: While I agree that replication should be transparent to applications, I also believe that databases that have to be published **must** be thought for replication from the ground up. Identity management in merge replication is totally PITA, for instance: if you know from the start you'll have to merge publish, it's one thing to stay away from.

Comment: @spaghettidba: Yes, I agree completely that if replication is in the cards, the database definitely has to be designed for it. Often simply following best practices will get most of the way there; it's the ugly, hairy legacy databases that tend to have the most design problems. From my experience, merge replication in particular is more challenging than any of the other replication mechanisms.

Comment: @spaghettidba and Jon: Just FYI, the use of `ROWGUIDCOL` in that context (i.e. not in a `CREATE TABLE` / `ALTER TABLE` statement) has been deprecated since at least [SQL Server 2008 R2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729(v=sql.105).aspx#Anchor_1) (search for FeatureID 182) in favor of `$ROWGUID`.

Answer (score 6):

I agree. As long as there is no need for the PK value to be able to change, then it would be better to use the existing uniqueidentifier column as the rowguidcol.

Answer (score 5):

"Basically, they say that the application should never bring into its domain something that is used by replication only (it's only "DBA stuff" for them)."

But it's not used for replication only.  It's also (and already) your PK.